# C# HttpWebRequest Server Certificate Validation Callback is called multiple times when the callback returns false

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, httpwebrequest

I have registered a callback for server certificate validation.

In the callback ,I will display the certificate to the user and if the user selects "Accept", i would add the certificate to the Certificate Store and return true. 
If the user rejects the certificate, the callback returns false.

There is no issue when the user has accepted the certificate.

PROBLEM: When the user rejects the certificate, the callback return false, the expectation was that the HttpWebRequest fails immediately. But I am seeing repeated certificate validation callback before finally failing the request with Timeout exception.
number of repetitions increase by 1 for every successive http request

how do I avoid this repeated callbacks for a single http request